# Outlook item find using filter not works for sent Items

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I try to filter mail Item using find, It works for inbox items but in the sent items it not find items using filter.

```
    private void GetNewSyncSentMail()
    { 
        Outlook.MAPIFolder mailSentFolder = null;
        Outlook.Items mailItemsSent = null;
        Outlook.MailItem mailItemSent = null;
        try
        {
            mailSentFolder = Globals.objNS.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail);
            Debug.DebugMessage(3, "Get folder "+mailSentFolder.Name );
            mailItemsSent = mailSentFolder.Items;
            Debug.DebugMessage(3, "Get sent items " + mailItemsSent.Count);
            mailItemSent = mailItemsSent.Find(filter) as Outlook.MailItem;
            while (mailItemSent != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    //Do something
                }
                catch (Exception exInner)
                {
                    Debug.DebugMessage(2, "Error  GetNewSyncSentMail" + exInner.Message);
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (mailItemSent != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mailItemSent);
                    mailItemSent = mailItemsSent.FindNext() as Outlook.MailItem;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.DebugMessage(2, "Error in GetNewSyncWSinoSentMail" + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (mailItemsSent != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mailItemsSent);
            if (mailSentFolder != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mailSentFolder);
        }
    }
```

there are sent items satisfy the filter in outlook. but it not find in the above code .

Here is the Filter

```
public static string syncW = (char)34 + "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/syncW" + (char)34;
    public static string sID = (char)34 + "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/sID" + (char)34;
    public string filter = "@SQL=((" + syncWi + " = 'True') AND ((" + sID + " = '') OR (" + sID + " IS NULL)))";
```

Comment: What specifically fails?

Comment: mailItemSent  is getting null. it not find the filter item

Comment: Does it work if you turn off the filter?

Comment: What do you mean, turn off the filter ?. The thing is this same code used to filter inbox folder items. It found the filter items, but not in sent folder items

Comment: Its a simple question to determine if it can even read the items in your sent items as mailitems

Comment: Yea if filter off it get all the mail items in the Sent Items folder

Comment: Ok so its something specific about the filter  a) what is the filter, b) is indexing on on the pc for deleted items? or is it returning nothing initially

Comment: yeah we would need the content of the `filter` to help you.

Comment: I updated question with filter.